# AS3 How to add seconds to (game) timer after hittest?

Tags: actionscript-3, timer, count, addition, seconds

I have a timer and a dynamic textfield wich displays the time. 
Everytime my movieclip hits an enemy I want the timer to add 4 sec. to the current count.
I would like to know why this isn't working:

```
timer.currentCount + 4;
```

(does nothing)

```
timer.currentCount += 4;
```

(error: property is read-only)

Am I in the right direction anyway and what should I change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the other answer you can't adjust the elapsed time of your Timer. What you could try to do is create a seperate var you call `var elapsedTime:Number;` every time the `timer` ticks you add 1 to this var. When the hittest occurs you can simply add 4 to it.

Because you're using a var to 'manipulate' the the time you don't need to use the `currentCount` anymore. Just refer to `elapsedTime` in an update function and you'll be fine.

It'll look like this:

```
var timer:Timer = new Timer(1000);
var elapsedTime:Number = 0;

timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTimerTick);

function onTimerTick(e:TimerEvent) : void
{
    elapsedTime++;
    updateTimerTxt();
}

function onHitTest() : void
{
    elapsedTime += 4;
    updateTimerTxt();
}

function updateTimerTxt() : void
{
    timertxt.text = String(elapsedTime);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I understand it, do you know how can I link the elapsed time to the dynamic textfield: timertxt.text = String(timer.currentCount) + elapsedTime;  ?

Comment: @Opoe That is a different question. I you have found the answer to your original question, then mark it as correct.

Comment: @AdamHarte I understand why you're saying that, but it has to do with my question, because I use a dynamic textfield to visualize the timer.

Comment: @Opoe I adjusted the answer for your problem. Next time, try to add this kind of information in you question. It'll help you get better answers.

Comment: @rvmook Thank you so much for your answer and advice! I'll keep it in mind :)

Answer (score 0):

The property `currentCount` is read only. There is no way you can modify the elapsed time of a timer. If you need to modify the timer then you can stop that and create a new one with modified interval.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So when you want to add or reduce seconds from your timer, you have to create a new timer?

Comment: You can never modify the elapsed time of an existing timer. Whether you need to create a new one or not depends on your overall design of the code. There might be other ways too based on your requirement and code structure.